# Is there a word similar to "coveted" in form but meaning "secretly"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word similar to "coveted" in form but meaning "secretly"? I remember there is, but can't recall which.

Comment: What do you mean, "in form"? "Coveted" only has one form, which is "coveted". Do you mean "in meaning"?

Comment: I think you mean [covert](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/covert), which means _secret_, not _secretly_.

Comment: When you get stuck for a word that you can't remember, it's sometimes a good idea to use a thesaurus to find synonyms. There are online sites [like this one here](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/secretly)